# Сгруппировать одинаковые соседние символы и указать число повторов для каждого

Tags: python, строки

Здравстуйте начал изучать питон, столкнулся с задачей, в которой нужно строку типа: 'aaabbcd' преобразовать в 'a3b2c1d1'. Подскажите решение.

Решение мое кривое:

```
s = input()
s2 = ''
i = 0
j = i + 1
ct = 1
while i < len(s):
    if s[i] == s[j]:
        ct += 1
    elif s[i] != s[j] or i == len(s):
        s2 += s[i] +  str(ct)
        ct = 1
    i += 1
print(s2)
```

Output:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если ввести например четыре а подряд, то ничего вообще не выводится.
И нормально ли объявлять пустую строку, когда неизвестна длинна строки?

Comment: Делайте через словарь и будет вам счастье. А еще опишите в вопросе правила преобразования

Comment: Преобразование (Алгоритм) называется - сжатие RLE - [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9), и в гугле по запросу RLE уже можно найти всевозможные реализации.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import re
result = ''
input = 'asskkkfhhh'

for (full, ch) in re.findall(r'(([a-z])\2*)', input):
    result += ch + str(len(full))

print result # a1s2k3f1h3
```

https://repl.it/K2ZY/0

Comment: Оказывается это *сжатие RLE* или *Кодирование длин серий*

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [99]: from itertools import groupby

In [100]: s = 'aaaasadsdasd'

In [101]: ''.join(['{}{}'.format(c, sum(1 for _ in g)) for c, g in groupby(s)])
Out[101]: 'a4s1a1d1s1d1a1s1d1'
```

или [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) если считаем все вхождения, а не только последовательные:

```
In [104]: from collections import Counter

In [105]: ''.join(['{}{}'.format(c,n) for c,n in Counter(s).items()])
Out[105]: 'a6s3d3'
```