# Как сделать стандартным кодом лучше, без библиотек?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

> Кодирование осуществляется следующим образом:
>   s = 'dddddgghhhqww' преобразуется в 'd5g2h3q1w2', то есть группы одинаковых 
>   символов исходной строки заменяются на этот 
>   символ и количество его повторений в этой позиции строки.

Мой код:

```
string = input()
index = string[0]
count = 0  # счетчик символов
output = ""  # строка для вывода кодирования 
for i in string:
    if i == index:
        count += 1
    else:
        output = output + "".join(index + str(count))
        count = 1
        index = i

print(output + index + str(count)))
```

Тесты проходит на курсе, но мне кажется тут не все правильно. Можно ли стандартным кодом, без привлечения библиотек сделать лучше? Но при этом нормально читаемым и понятным кодом.

Comment: Что значит "тесты проходят на курсе"?

Comment: Это задачка с одного онлайн курса. Я ее решил. Их внутренняя система тестирования ее приняла и зачла как верный вариант. Но сложилось какое то чувство, что тут что то не совсем верно.

Comment: `output = output + "".join(index + str(count))` -> `output += index + str(count)`

Comment: [еще несколько решений с использованием встроенных модулей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711295/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется что алгоритм в вопросе нормальный и если предлагать что-то подобное, то с использованием готовых инструментов.

Например, под эту задачу идеально подходит [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def my_foo(s):
    return ''.join('{}{}'.format(i, len(list(group))) for i, group in groupby(s))

    # # Тот же алгоритм, но в более привычном виде
    # result = ''
    # 
    # for c, group in groupby(s):
    #     number = len(list(group))
    #     result += c + str(number)
    # 
    # return result


s = 'dddddgghhhqww'
print(my_foo(s))  # d5g2h3q1w2
assert my_foo(s) == 'd5g2h3q1w2'
```

---

Меня натолкнуло на мысль, что раз код `groupby` доступен, то его можно немного изменить, чтобы тот сразу подсчитывал подгруппы:

```
class my_groupby:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.it = iter(iterable)
        self.tgtkey = self.currkey = object()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while self.currkey == self.tgtkey:
            self.currkey = next(self.it)    # Exit on StopIteration

        self.tgtkey = self.currkey
        return self.currkey, self._grouper(self.tgtkey)

    def _grouper(self, tgtkey):
        number = 0

        while self.currkey == tgtkey:
            number += 1

            try:
                currvalue = next(self.it)
            except StopIteration:
                return number

            self.currkey = currvalue

        return number


def my_foo__my_groupby(s):
    return ''.join(i + str(number) for i, number in my_groupby(s))


print(my_foo__my_groupby(s))  # d5g2h3q1w2
assert my_foo__my_groupby(s) == 'd5g2h3q1w2'
```