# Алгоритм "сжатия" на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите понять, что именно в моем коде не верно?
Задача: написать алгоритм сжатия геномного кода.
Пример:
Входные данные: AACAA
Выходные данные: A2C1A2

```
genome = input()
a = 0
b = 1
result = ""
c = 1
one = "1"
for i in genome:
  if b > len(genome) - 1:
    break
  if genome[a] == genome[b]:
    c += 1
  elif c >= 2:
    c = str(c)
    result = genome[a] + c
    c = int(c)
    c = 1
  else:
    result = genome[a] + one
  a += 1
  b += 1
print(result)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711295/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/711297#711297

Comment: Алгоритм называется RLE - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: @MaxU так это дубль.

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что бросается в глаза, это переменная "i" в цикле, которая не используется. И в общем у вас есть лишние движения.

```
genome = input()
a = 0 # счетчик текущего символа
b = genome[0] # первый символ входных данных
result = ""
for i in genome:
    if i == b: # сравниваем, если одинаковые, увеличиваем счетчик
        a += 1  
    else:
        result += b + str(a) # иначе, сохраняем в результат 
                                     # символ и его количество
        a = 1 # сбрасываем счетчик
        b = i # задаем переменной новый символ, сменивший старый
result += b + str(a) # сохраняем данные по последнему символу      
print(result) # выводим результат
```

Mожно еще строку `result += b + str(a)` вынести в отдельную функцию, но в данном коде это не имеет смысла.