# Подсчет количества букв

Tags: python, if, for

Есть код:

```
from collections import Counter
    
def chec(stroka):
    c = []
    for k, v in Counter(stroka).items():
        if v > 1:
            c.append(f'{k}{v}')
        elif v == 1:
            c.append(f'{k}')
    print(*c, sep='', end='')
        
chec('aaabbvb')
```

На выходе `a3b3v`

А нужно `a3b2vb`

Comment: А для чего нужны строки `stroka`, `b = list(stroka)`, `dict(Counter(b))`?

Comment: `Counter` не подходит для этой задачи, как видно `b` из конца строки была подсчитана

Comment: `itertools.groupby` решит задачу.

Comment: PD: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/711295/Сгруппировать-одинаковые-соседние-символы-и-указать-число-повторов-для-каждого

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этой задачи лучше всего использовать [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

text = 'aaabbvb'

for c, v in groupby(text):
    count = len(list(v))
    print(f'{c}{count if count > 1 else ""}', end='')

# a3b2vb
```